# Elastic Kibana heatmaps

Tags: elasticsearch, data-visualization, kibana

I'm trying to generate a heatmap on kibana with elasticsearch. I've pushed data to an index and created a index pattern and visualized this kibana heatmap.

The x-axis is timestamp and y-axis is float values for each timestamp.

[image]

What I want is to customize this heatmap so I can create different color level based on whether `yhat` is greater than or less than `yhat_upper`

Currently these heat values are automatically assigned.

Is there any way I can do this?